# ASP.NET webforms authentication not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, webforms

I'm learning ASP.NET Webforms and I wanted to create a simple chat app.

I've created a `Default.aspx` form which is my login page. It contains only one `<asp:Login/>` control for now and it's goal is to redirect to another page if the user is authenticated. By this, I mean when the user exists in my SQL database.

It all works fine, except one thing. I wanted to use option "remember me", but it doesn't work as excepted. For `Default.aspx`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Chatroom.aspx");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this makes the condition being always true. I've been searching for a while and I added to my `web.config` following lines:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Default.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="1" slidingExpiration="false"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Because of `UnobtrusiveValidationError` I also added the following:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

But now, I am always redirected to the `Chatroom.aspx`, even after 1 minute of waiting. I've noticed in my project properties that Anonymous authentication is disables (which is ok), but Windows Authentication is enabled. I thought it should be turned off, because I want to use form authentication, but after  turning it off I am denied to access the `Default.aspx` (401.2 - Unauthorized).

What is there, that I'm missing of?

Comment: What is your login method? how you implement remember me?

Comment: Looks like you have anonymous authentication turned on in IIS.

Comment: @PankajKapare Isn't setting anonymous authentication to false, as I've mentioned in the question, enough?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. My bad.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I needed to enable anonymous authentication and disable windows authentication. Because now it works..